# Java Socket Bind Error

Tags: java, sockets, networking, local

I have been having trouble about socket usage in java. First of all, let me explain what I want to do with sockets in java. I want to connect my laptop over the Internet via it. My laptop has a server and a client must connect over the internet. Because I have a router to handle my local network and I do not want to lead a port on the router to my laptop, I need to follow the path "internet->router->localNetwork->mylaptop". The problem is I have found a way to use both the internet ip address and the local ip address; However, it throws an exception : `"Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use"`

The code I try is :

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName("YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY");
Socket socket = new Socket(addr, 1111, local, 1111); // The line I have got exception
```

With leading router port to my laptop, I can run this code for the similar purposes:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 1111);
```

*Xs stand for internet ip address

*Ys stand for local ip address

*Codes are belongs to client side of code

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you have a router with Internet (WAN) IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX with NAT, and you have a laptop with Local (LAN) IP YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY connected to the router, and you assume that

```
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"), 1111, InetAddress.getByName("YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY"), 1111);
```

Will connect to the laptop. **That is not correct.**

Documentation of the constructor of `Socket` class you are using tells:

> Creates a socket and connects it to the specified remote host on the specified remote port. The Socket will also bind() to the local address and port supplied.

That is **not** what you want.

You can't connect to a device behind NAT like this. You have to "lead a port on the router".

Comment: Ok that is great you have got the point. However, what if I dont want to lead a port on the router?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the local address:port of the Socket, and you are doing so incorrectly. Remove the last two parameters.